# How can I fix this logback problem I am having with Spring Boot 3?

Tags: spring-boot, logback, spring-logback, logback-classic, spring-boot-3

I am trying to migrate to Spring Boot 3. My logging implementation is logback.

I get this error : *logback.SpringBootJoranConfigurator Could not find valid configuration instructions. Exiting.*

After the migration, including the migration to Jakarta EE, the server doesn't start because the logback configuration is erroneous.

I have ensured that there is a parseable logback-XXXX.xml and application.properties

However in *ImplicitModelAction#end* *parentModel* is null

```
Model parentModel = interpretationContext.peekModel();
```

and so I get the warning parent model not found. However, as I mentioned before, the config seems parseable and findable.

Furthermore, it is actually logging to the console (as configured).

At start up it logs to the console the following infos, warnings and error.

```
16:32:13,832 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback-test.xml] at [file:/C:/*/*/*logback-test.xml]
16:32:54,154 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.ImplicitModelAction - Could not find parent model.
16:35:05,868 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.ImplicitModelAction -  Will not add current implicit model as subModel.
16:35:07,009 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@770d3326 - Could not find valid configuration instructions. Exiting.
```

Does anyone know what I can try?